# typescript replaceent for require inside a function in nodejs

Tags: node.js, typescript, require

I trying to convert a nodejs project to TypeScript and while mostly I did not faced really difficult obstacles during this process, the codebase has few gotchas like this, mostly in startup code:

```
    function prepareConfiguration() {
       let cloudConfigLoader = require('../utils/cloud-config');
       return cloudConfigLoader.ensureForFreshConfig().then(function() {
           //do some stuff
       });
    }
```

I may be need just an advice on which approach for refactoring this has less code changes to be made to make it work in TypeScript fashion.

In response to comments, more details:
That require loads the node module, not a JSON file. From that module the ensureForFreshConfig function contacts with a cloud service to load a list of values to rebuild a configuration state object.
Problem is that mdule was made in standard node approach of "module is isngleton object" and its independencies include auth component that will be ready only when the shown require call is made. I know it is not best a way to do so..
Typesript does not allow "mport that module later" except with dynamyc import which is problematic as mentiond in comment.
The "good" approach is to refactor that part of startup and make the ensureForFreshConfig and its dependency to initiate its ntenras on demand via cnstructors.. I just hoped ofr some soluiton to reduce things to be remade durng this transition to the TypeScript

Comment: What is this specific `require()` doing?  Is it just loading and parsing some JSON or is it loading an actual module of code that needs to be run?

Comment: You can read about dynamic import in Typescript here: https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2018/01/14/typescript-2-4-dynamic-import-expressions Node might still have some issues with the import statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { cloudConfigLoader } from '../utils/cloud-config'

async function prepareConfiguration() {
  await cloudConfigLoader.ensureForFreshConfig()

  // do some stuff
  // return some-stuff
}
```

> The function is to be used as follows.

```
await prepareConfiguration()
```

Comment: I will try this suggestion later, when wlll return to the TypeScripting task of the project I working on.